# Brezis- Functional Analysis, Corollary 1.4

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding the proof to this corollary. It goes

> For every $x \in E$ we have
>   \begin{align*}
> ||x|| = \sup_{f \in E^*,||f|| \leq 1} |\langle f,x \rangle| = \max_{f \in E^*, ||f|| \leq 1} |\langle f,x \rangle|
> \end{align*}

where $E^*$ is the dual space of $E$, they are using the notation $|\langle f,x \rangle| = f(x)$, and $||f|| = \sup_{x \in E, ||x|| \leq 1} |f(x)|$.

The first line of the proof goes,

> It is clear that
>   \begin{align*}
> \sup_{f \in E^*, ||f|| \leq 1} |\langle f,x \rangle| \leq ||x||
> \end{align*}

Why is this obvious? For any $f \in E^*$ such that $||f|| \leq 1$, we just know that for any $x \in E$ such that $||x|| \leq 1$, we have $|\langle f,x \rangle| \leq 1$. I tried reasoning by first supposing that $\sup_{f \in E^*, ||f|| \leq 1} |\langle f,x \rangle| > ||x||$ so that there would exist an $f \in E^*$ with $||f|| \leq 1$ and $|\langle f, x \rangle| > ||x||$ but I don't see how this leads to a contradiction.

Any hints? Maybe I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the highlighted inequality because for $f\in E^*$ and $x\in E$ we have $$|f(x)|\leq\|f\|\|x\|,$$
 and you're taking the supremum over $\|f\|\leq1$. This can be seen by observing that for $x\in E$ nonzero, $x/\|x\|$ has norm $1$, so 
$$\left|f\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right|\leq \sup_{x \in E, ||x|| \leq 1} |f(x)|=\|f\|.$$
Multiplying by $\|x\|$ yields $|f(x)|\leq\|f\|\|x\|$.

If you have any further questions, let me know and I will edit.